# gremlin docker 3.6.4 conf path issue

Tags: docker, gremlin, gremlin-server

I am trying to use https://hub.docker.com/r/tinkerpop/gremlin-server
as part of https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/gremlin-python-tutorial

```
docker run tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.2 conf/gremlin-server-modern.yaml
```

works as advertised

when doing

```
docker run tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.6.4 conf/gremlin-server-modern.yaml
```

as described in https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.6.4/reference/#gremlin-server

i get:

WARNING: /opt/gremlin-server//opt/gremlin-server/conf/gremlin-server.yaml is unreadable
Configuration file not found.

```
docker run tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.6.4
```

I tried with multiple other 3.5 and 3.6 versions and also no luck ...

**whats the reason for this IMHO buggy behavior and how can it be fixed?**

```bash
docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
uname -a
...Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0
```

using Docker for Mac on older Mac computer

Comment: I tried the `docker run` command using exactly the formulation you gave above on a Ubuntu machine and it worked for me without any issues. The path in the error message you are getting looks strange. `/opt/gremlin-server/` appears twice. What is your Docker environment? Is it possible a volume mapping is in place? What error do you get when you try to run it without specifying a yaml file?

Comment: Firstly, that looks like a bug in an existing piece of software, so check the bug trackers. Also, check release notes or browse the versioning system, maybe the cause can be tracked down. This Q isn't really suitable for SO though, since it's not about programming, I would say.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i have added the context https://github.com/WolfgangFahl/gremlin-python-tutorial to make sure the readers know this is about programming in python in the end

Answer (score 0):

On a recent docker version things run fine

```
Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086
```